# Custom Solutions Upgrade is required from SP 2013 to SP 2016?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, upgrade-sharepoint

Hai have SharePoint 2013 Content database required to upgrade to SharePoint 2016,
I started now the Test Upgrade https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-content-databases

SP 2013 Farm has deployed Custom Solutions that was targeted to .Net Framework 4.5 my question is when i take backup and deploy in Test SP 2016 farm is these farm solutions works?
or
Sp2013 Solutions is required to upgrade that SharePoint 2016 built on  Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a short answer, **Yes**, it would work!

The SharePoint handles the `.NET Assembly redirects`. so that the SharePoint 2013 dlls will be redirected automatically to SharePoint 2016 dlls.

**If you have noticed that some WSPs don't work, so you have to do the following:**

- If you have the source solution of the deployed WSP, so you should do the following:

  - In SharePoint 2016 Test environment, Install VS 2017/2019.
  - Install [Office / SharePoint template in Visual Studio 2017](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/tag/install-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/).
  - Open your solution using VS, The VS would upgrade your solution automatically. otherwise, you have to remove all `SharePoint.dll` references and re-add them again.
  - Finally, build and deploy your solution.
- If you just have the WSP files, so you should redeploy theses solutions again as the following:

  - Retract and [remove the installed SharePoint WSP Solutions](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/uninstall-sharepoint-wsp-solutions/)
  - Then [install the WSP solution](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/) again.

Comment: Thanks great answer